Joomla 4/5 default template cassiopeia, preconnect and preload not wotking
I'm testing the joomla 4/5 default template cassiopeia, we should be able to preload, preconnect resources with getPreloadManager like this:
        $this->getPreloadManager()->preconnect('https://fonts.googleapis.com/', ['crossorigin' => 'anonymous']);
        $this->getPreloadManager()->preconnect('https://fonts.gstatic.com/', ['crossorigin' => 'anonymous']);
        $this->getPreloadManager()->preload($paramsFontScheme, ['as' => 'style', 'crossorigin' => 'anonymous']);

but when I check the output, I can't see the preload and preconnect links added? did I miss anything?


Joomla uses HTTP headers instead of HTML links for preloading. You can check if the header is sent by inspecting response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 26 Oct 2024 12:59:28 GMT
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
referrer-policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin
Link: <https://fonts.googleapis.com/>; rel="preconnect"; crossorigin="anonymous",<https://fonts.gstatic.com/>; rel="preconnect"; crossorigin="anonymous",<https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap>; rel="preload"; as="style"; crossorigin="anonymous"
Expires: Wed, 17 Aug 2005 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 26 Oct 2024 12:59:29 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=62
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Link
